# How to plot the log likelihood associated with each iteration of EM algorithm and the density of each component?

Tags: r

I am new to R. I am working with mixture model and would like to get the plot the of the log likelihood associated with each iteration of the EM algorithm and the density of each component. I would like to do that manually.

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are able to calculate the log-likelihood and density in each iteration of your EM algorithm.

The general way to plot a function in R (of which a log-likelihood and density are) is to (a) create inputs for the function over the domain your interested in, (b)  generate outputs from your function and save in a data frame, then (c) plot the function using the data frame. Here's an example of plotting a mixture model density using the 2D mixture model given by:

```
library(mvtnorm)
# example 2D mixture density
mixture_model_density <- function(x){
  a <- 0.3
  a * dmvnorm(x = x, mean = c(3, 2)) + (1 - a) * dmvnorm(x = x, mean = c(2.5,5.5))
}
```

(a) Create inputs:

```
grid_space <- 0.2
x <- seq(from = 0, to = 10, by = grid_space)
y <- seq(from = 0, to = 10, by = grid_space)
grid_mat <- expand.grid(x=x,y=y)
```

(b) Generate outputs:

```
 grid_mat$mm_dens <- mixture_model_density(grid_mat)
```

(c) Plot results:

```
ggplot(grid_mat) + stat_contour(aes(x = x, y = y, z = mm_dens))
```

[image: Contour plot]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Not sure how to find log likelihood for each iteration but I will work and see. I just replicate one code (because I am new to R) and tried to get the plot. Thanks a gain.

Comment: @Silver what's the package/code you're using for the EM algorithm? Maybe you can update your question with some more details on that?

Comment: I replicated this code "http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/55132/em-algorithm-manually-implemented/57928#57928" (in the answer). But, I was confused why the author of the code used "mysum*(pi1(p1*dnorm) so here the author repeat pi1 two times. And I could not produce the plot.

Comment: In the initialisation line `loglik[2]<-mysum(pi1*(log(pi1)+...`, the first `pi1` here is not `tau1` because `pi1` and `pi2` each start at `0.5` therefore they sum to `1` and `tau1` can be simplified. Look later in the code where `loglik[k+1]<-mysum(tau1*(log(pi1)+...`. As for the plot I need some more information. Maybe you can post a new question with a minimum working example with some example data and code of your first attempt?

Comment: Ok I will send my code as soon as I can. Thanks a lot for your replay.