# Observation from each cluster from EM algorithm manually implemented

Tags: expectation-maximization

I am interesting in implementing the EM algorithm manually. And I did it. However, I am still do not know how to get the observation from each cluster? For example, after run the EM algorithm, the data will be divided into two subgroups (as we have only two clusters here). My question is, how to access the observation within each cluster? How do I know that this observation is belong to cluster 1? I understand the idea but do not know how to  extract them from the following code? What  R code should I run to get this information?

I followed the EM algorithm.

```
setwd("~/Downloads/")
load("datem.Rdata")

x <- dat

# initial values
pi1<-0.5
pi2<-0.5
mu1<--0.01
mu2<-0.01
sigma1<-sqrt(0.01)
sigma2<-sqrt(0.02)
loglik<- rep(NA, 1000)
loglik[1]<-0
loglik[2]<-mysum(pi1*(log(pi1)+log(dnorm(dat,mu1,sigma1))))+mysum(pi2*(log(pi2)+log(dnorm(dat,mu2,sigma2))))

mysum <- function(x) {
  sum(x[is.finite(x)])
}
logdnorm <- function(x, mu, sigma) {
  mysum(sapply(x, function(x) {logdmvnorm(x, mu, sigma)}))  
}
tau1<-0
tau2<-0
#k<-1
k<-2

# loop
while(abs(loglik[k]-loglik[k-1]) >= 0.00001) {
  # E step
  tau1<-pi1*dnorm(dat,mean=mu1,sd=sigma1)/(pi1*dnorm(x,mean=mu1,sd=sigma1)+pi2*dnorm(dat,mean=mu2,sd=sigma2))
  tau2<-pi2*dnorm(dat,mean=mu2,sd=sigma2)/(pi1*dnorm(x,mean=mu1,sd=sigma1)+pi2*dnorm(dat,mean=mu2,sd=sigma2))
  tau1[is.na(tau1)] <- 0.5
  tau2[is.na(tau2)] <- 0.5

  # M step
  pi1<-mysum(tau1)/length(dat)
  pi2<-mysum(tau2)/length(dat)

  mu1<-mysum(tau1*x)/mysum(tau1)
  mu2<-mysum(tau2*x)/mysum(tau2)

  sigma1<-mysum(tau1*(x-mu1)^2)/mysum(tau1)
  sigma2<-mysum(tau2*(x-mu2)^2)/mysum(tau2)

  #  loglik[k]<-sum(tau1*(log(pi1)+log(dnorm(x,mu1,sigma1))))+sum(tau2*(log(pi2)+log(dnorm(x,mu2,sigma2))))
  loglik[k+1]<-mysum(tau1*(log(pi1)+logdnorm(x,mu1,sigma1)))+mysum(tau2*(log(pi2)+logdnorm(x,mu2,sigma2)))
  k<-k+1
}

# compare
library(mixtools)
gm<-normalmixEM(x,k=2,lambda=c(0.5,0.5),mu=c(-0.01,0.01),sigma=c(0.01,0.02))
gm$lambda
 gm$mu
gm$sigma

gm$loglik
Historgram`
```

The source of the code is from the following answer:

[EM algorithm manually implemented](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/55132/em-algorithm-manually-implemented)

Comment: You have to describe the problem much more clearly as part of the question and not rely on readers processing first the earlier question & answer(s). Note that it is easy to cut and paste in MathJax and that, further, you can copy the original code by editing a question or an answer without making any change to these.

Comment: @Xi'an Thanks for your great comment. I will do it.